# Notification with messageStyle and dataset() an image not working

Tags: android, push-notification, xamarin.android, notifications

I'm trying to display a notification using messageStyle with a person object and an image passed by SetData but i'm only getting the info from the person in the notification and no Image.
Using a bigpicture style i can get the image on large icon and expanded so its not a problem with the url. Any help would be appreciated since by following the documentation i got in a dead end :/
Thanks, i got a sample of the code iam using to display the notification message.

```
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationMessage.Data?.Media?.Url))
                {   
                    var imageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(notificationMessage.Data.Media.Url);
                    MessagingStyle.Message messaget = new MessagingStyle.Message("Picture", notification.Timestamp.Ticks, notificationPerson)
                    .SetData("image/", imageUri);
                    messageStyle.AddMessage(messaget);
                }
                else messageStyle.AddMessage(notification.Message ?? "", notification.Timestamp.Ticks, notificationPerson);

                notificationBuilder.SetStyle(messageStyle);
                notificationManager.Notify(uniqueId, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Comment: Please do not use Apply NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle to display Image, This function just used display sequential messages between any number of people. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#message-style. If you want to display Image in the notification, please use bigpicture style.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but my objective is to show the image in the conversation, for exemple like whatsapp, and this is the method used for that. I'am able to do it work by passing the android resource to set data, but not working when passing from Url from my server

Comment: Here is a workaround, if the image cannot be loaded in the ` NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle`. You can replace the Image by character( for example, when you want to should the picture, you can replace it by `[Picture]` in to Messages)